# Highest of morning first candle

Tags: algorithmic-trading, pine-script

I want to get `high` of the first morning candle. `highest(series, length)` returns highest of last (`length`) numbers of candle. How can I get `high` of the first morning candle?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you please have a look at this link: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask We need to see your code. So far it's pretty hard to understand your question. Thanks.

Comment: Pretend you are someone else who knows nothing about the problem you are working to solve. Then read your question and think about what additional information would be required for someone else reading it.

Answer (score 0):

That could be achieved like that:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script", overlay=true)
dayStart = time('D')

dayStartHigh = 0.0
dayStartHigh := dayStartHigh[1]

// make sure it's a new day
if (dayStart[1] != dayStart)
    dayStartHigh := high    

plot(dayStartHigh)
```